# Reference Request: Vertex Algebras

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras

I am currently a graduate student in mathematics with an interest in vertex algebras. I am comfortable with the algebraic aspects and would like to learn more about the geometric aspects. The issue is that I'm finding the standard text on the subject (Vertex Algebras and Algebraic Curves by Frenkel and Ben-Zvi) to be very challenging and almost inaccessible. Apart from this text, does anyone have any recommendations for texts to learn about geometric aspects of the following: vertex algebras, conformal blocks, the KZ equations? I'm struggling to find any alternative texts on these topics, let alone more accessible ones.

Comment: What about *Conformal Field Theory and Topology* by Toshitake Kohno?

Comment: For KZ equations, you could try the book "Lectures on Representation Theory and Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov Equations", Etingof-Frenkel-Kirillov. If you happen to be comfortable with physics terminology, the conformal field theory book of di Francesco-Mathieu-Senechal is the best reference I know. Unfortunately, although the majority of that book is math, it is written in entirely in physical terminology and will probably be impenetrable if you are not comfortable with that language...

Comment: Those are both great suggestions. Thanks!